# problem during installing multi2sim simulator

Tags: multi-core

I'am new to ubuntu and when I'am trying to install multi2sim I get this error:

```
CXX      WorkItemIsa.o
WorkItemIsa.cc: In member function ‘void SI::WorkItem::ISA_V_CVT_I32_F32_Impl(SI::Instruction*)’:
WorkItemIsa.cc:2335:23: error: ‘isnan’ was not declared in this scope
  else if (isnan(fvalue) || fvalue == 0.0f || fvalue == -0.0f)
                       ^
WorkItemIsa.cc:2335:23: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from WorkItemIsa.cc:22:0:
/usr/include/c++/5/cmath:641:5: note:   ‘std::isnan’
     isnan(_Tp __x)
     ^
Makefile:456: recipe for target 'WorkItemIsa.o' failed
make[4]: *** [WorkItemIsa.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/yasmine/Downloads/multi2sim-5.0/src/arch/southern-islands/emulator'
Makefile:360: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/yasmine/Downloads/multi2sim-5.0/src/arch/southern-islands'
Makefile:363: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/yasmine/Downloads/multi2sim-5.0/src/arch'
Makefile:568: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yasmine/Downloads/multi2sim-5.0/src'
Makefile:570: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I don't know what should I do or how can I solve it !!
Can anyone familiar with this simulator help me ?!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, and what C++ compiler?

Comment: for Ubuntu 16.04 
for C++ compiler g++

Comment: What g++ version specifically (`g++ --version`)? It seems to build OK on 14.04, both with the default g++ 4.8.4 and with g++ 5.3.0 installed from the toolchain-r PPA. Sorry I can't suggest anything else.

Comment: g++ version 5.3.1

Never mind thanks for your help 
i will follow your advice

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver it's working now but I face another problem when I use (M2S) options  get this error  

yasmine@yasmine-Inspiron-5537:~/Documents/multi2sim-5.0$ m2s --x86-sim detailed test-args how are you

; Multi2Sim 5.0 - A Simulation Framework for CPU-GPU Heterogeneous Computing
; Please use command 'm2s --help' for a list of command-line options.
; Simulation alpha-numeric ID: VrvjQ


[ELF Reader] [/home/yasmine/Documents/multi2sim-5.0/test-args] Error: Cannot
open file

 Can you help me ?!

Comment: Sorry you will need to find someone who is familiar with the program's usage

Answer (score 2):

Just find this line:

`else if (isnan(fvalue) || fvalue == 0.0f || fvalue == -0.0f)`

that is inside the `/multi2sim5.0/scr/arch/southern-islands/emulator/WorkItemIsa.cc` file.

And add `std::` before `isnan`. It should be like this:

`else if (std::isnan(fvalue) || fvalue == 0.0f || fvalue == -0.0f)`

Answer (score 0):

Installing Multi2Sim on Ubuntu 16.04 isn't supposed to be done with `make` .The main README of the project's Github page(https://github.com/Multi2Sim/multi2sim#readme) says to do the following:

1. Install Docker(https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/)
2. Inside the Docker terminal, run the following to compile and install Multi2Sim:

   ```
   docker pull multi2sim/multi2sim
   docker run -it multi2sim/multi2sim bash
   ```
3. To run Multi2Sim, open the Docker terminal and run:

   ```
   m2s
   ```